# opencv python - applying rotation matrix from rodrigues function

Tags: python, opencv, transformation, opencv3.0

I am trying to simulate an image standing out of a marker. This is my code so far which does what is pictured. Essentially, I just want to rotate the image to appear to stand out orthogonal to the checkerboard.

As you can see, I use the code to find the transformation matrix between a normalized square image and the corresponding checkerboard corners. I then use `warpPerspective` to get the image you see. I know that I can use the rotation vectors from the `solvePnP` to obtain a rotation matrix through `rodrigues()` but I dont know what the next step is

[image]

```
def transformTheSurface(inputFrame):
    ret, frameLeft = capleft.read()
    capGray = cv2.cvtColor(frameLeft,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    found, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(capGray, (5,4), None, cv2.CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE + cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH ) #,None,cv2.CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK)
    if (found):
        npGameFrame = pygame.surfarray.array3d(inputFrame)
        inputFrameGray = cv2.cvtColor(npGameFrame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        cv2.drawChessboardCorners(frameLeft, (5,4), corners, found)
        q = corners[[0, 4, 15, 19]]
        ret, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.solvePnP(objp, corners, mtx, dist)
        ptMatrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform( muffinCoords, q)

        npGameFrame = cv2.flip(npGameFrame, 0)

        ptMatrixWithXRot = ptMatrix * rodRotMat[0]
        #inputFrameConv = cv2.cvtColor(npGameFrame,cv2.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY)
        transMuffin = cv2.warpPerspective(npGameFrame, ptMatrix, (640, 480)) #, muffinImg, cv2.INTER_NEAREST, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,  0)
```

## EDIT:

I have added some more code, in hopes to create my own 3x3 transformation matrix. I used the [following reference](http://jepsonsblog.blogspot.in/2012/11/rotation-in-3d-using-opencvs.html) . Here is my code for that:

```
#initialization happens earlier in code
muffinCoords = np.zeros((4,2), np.float32)
muffinCoords[0] = (0,0)
muffinCoords[1] = (200,0)
muffinCoords[2] = (0,200)
muffinCoords[3] = (200,200)

A1 = np.zeros((4,3), np.float32)
A1[0] = (1,0,322)
A1[1] = (0,1,203)
A1[2] = (0,0,0)
A1[3] = (0,0,1)

R = np.zeros((4,4), np.float32)
R[3,3] = 1.0

T = np.zeros((4,4), np.float32)
T[0] = (1,0,0,0)
T[1] = (0,1,0,0)
T[2] = (0,0,1,0)
T[3] = (0,0,0,1)
#end initialization

#load calib data derived using cv2.calibrateCamera, my Fx and Fy are about 800
loadedCalibFileMTX = np.load('calibDataMTX.npy')
mtx = np.zeros((3,4), np.float32)
mtx[:3,:3] = loadedCalibFileMTX
```

[image: output of camera calibration]

```
#this is new to my code, creating what I interpret as Rx*Ry*Rz
ret, rvecCalc, tvecs = cv2.solvePnP(objp, corners, loadedCalibFileMTX, dist)
rodRotMat = cv2.Rodrigues(rvecCalc)
R[:3,:3] = rodRotMat[0]
```

[image: output of R]

```
#then I create T
T[0,3] = tvecs[0]
T[1,3] = tvecs[1]
T[2,3] = tvecs[2]
```

[image: output of T]

```
# CREATING CUSTOM TRANSFORM MATRIX
# A1 -> 2d to 3d projection matrix
# R-> rotation matrix as calculated by solve PnP, or Rx * Ry * Rz
# T -> converted translation matrix, reference from site, vectors pulled from tvecs of solvPnP
# mtx -> 3d to 2d matrix
# customTransformMat = mtx * (T * (R * A1)) {this is intended calculation of following}
first = np.dot(R, A1)
second = np.dot(T, first)
finalCalc = np.dot(mtx, second)
```

[image: output of finalCalc as followed by formula in comments]

```
finalNorm = finalCalc/(finalCalc[2,2]) # to make sure that the [2,2] element is 1
```

[image: output of finalNorm]

```
transMuffin = cv2.warpPerspective(npGameFrame, finalNorm, (640, 480), None, cv2.INTER_NEAREST, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,  0)
#transMuffin is returned as undefined here, any help?

# using the cv2.getPerspectiveTransform method to find what you can find pictured at the top
ptMatrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform( muffinCoords, q)
```

[image: output of ptMatrix]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the right methodology. you can find the code here https://github.com/mikezucc/augmented-reality-fighter-pygame

## NOTICE:

Almost ALL of the game code is written by Leif Theiden, and is under license specified in the .py files. The code relevant to the computer vision is in states.py. I used the game to just show that it can be done for others looking to get started in simple computer vision.

My code opens a thread everytime a new surface (PyGame for frame simply) is called to be displayed on the main window. I start a thread at that point and execute a simple computer vision function that does the following:

1. Searches a camera stream frame for the 5x4 chessboard (cv2.findChessboardCorners)
2. The found corners are then drawn onto the image
3. Using cv2.solvePnP, the approximate pose (Rotation and translation vectors) are derived
4. The 3d points that describe a square are then projected from the 3d space determined by step 3 into a 2d space. this is used to convert a predertimined 3d structure into something you can use to graph on a 2d image.
5. However, this step instead finds the transformation to get from a set of 2d square points (the dimensions of the game frame) to the newly found projected 2d points (of the 3d frame). Now you can see that what we are trying to is simply do a two step transformation.
6. I then perform a basic tutorial style addition of the captured stream frame and the transformed game frame to get a final image

Variables:

+`from3dTransMatrix` -> points of the projected 3d structure into 2d points. these are the red dots you see

+`q` -> this is the reference plane that we determine the pose from

+`ptMatrix` -> the final transformation, to transform the game frame to fit in the projected frame

Check out the screens in the topmost folder ;]

enjoy!